# Как передать самое крайнее значение выпадающего списка?

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Есть функция которая подгружает дерево категорий с разным уровнем вложенности от 2 до 5 уровней.

```
function get_cat_options($parentID, $db) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `parent` = '. intval($parentID) .';';
  $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  ob_start();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {?>
    <select class="row-item-2 subcat">
        <option value=""><?= 'Категория'?></option>
        <? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {?>
          <option value="<? echo $row->id; ?>"><?  echo $row->name; ?></option>
        <?}?>
    </select>
  <?} else {?>
    <span class="subcat" style="color:green">OK!</span>
  <?}
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать самое крайние значение выпадающего списка методом пост?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем корректен. php не может передать форму клиенту. php ее сам как раз обрабатывает.
Если подразумевается, как выделить в селекте последний пункт по умолчанию, то можно получить все кол-во записей в отдельную переменную и затем в цикле проверять когда дошли до конца, то вывести дополнительный атрибут в option - selected

```
function get_last_cat($parentID, $db) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `parent` = '. intval($parentID) .';';
  $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  ob_start();
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
  $i = 0;
  if ($rows > 0) {?>
    <select class="row-item-2 subcat">
        <option value=""><?= 'Категория'?></option>
        <? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {?>
          <option value="<? echo $row->id; ?>" <? echo $rows == ++$i ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?  echo $row->name; ?></option>
        <?}?>
    </select>
  <?} else {?>
    <span class="subcat" style="color:green">OK!</span>
  <?}
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Второй вариант. Как получить последнюю запись из БД:

```
function get_last_cat($parentID, $db) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `parent` = '. intval($parentID) .' order by id desc limit 1;';
  $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $lastCat = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
  return $lastCat;
}
```

Comment: Да, не совсем правильно вопрос задал, интересует как взять значение последнего пункта, для того чтобы его передать в БД

Comment: Как получить последнюю запись в определенном порядке, привел пример выше.